# d3 SVG text element background-color with getBBox() wrong order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to add a background color to the text elements. I realise I cannot set a background color using CSS styles because this is SVG text, so I tried to append rectangles but to success:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/OaYgLY)

```
let g = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(["1 year", "2 years", "3 years", "4 years", "5 years"])
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (markerCirclesScale(name) + 330) + "," + (fullSVGHeight / 2 - 60)  + ")" );
        g.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", 10)
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("y", function(d,i){
                return i * (-65);
            })
            .text(function(d){
                return d;
            })

        g.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", function(d){ return this.parentNode.getBBox().x - 10;})
                    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return  this.parentNode.getBBox().y })
                    .attr("width", function(d){ return this.parentNode.getBBox().width + 20;})
                    .attr("height", function(d) {return 40;})
                    .style("fill", "#80d6c7");
```

However I realised changing order in DOM doest the trick, why this doesn't work by changing code order?!

[image]

Comment: I think you are appending text then covering them with background rect

Comment: Thank you Ahmad! Can you please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting the `<text>` elements, and then covering them up with `<rect>` elements.

If you simply reverse the order in which you are appending these elements, then text will show up.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvYXwq?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated! It works, however I noticed that your ` `bx.append("text")` block is unnecessary, only one line that does the trick Y position for rect `.attr("y", function(d, i){ return  -20-i*65})`, instead of `.attr("y", function(d, i){ return  this.parentNode.getBBox().y })`

Comment: `bx.append` I was experimenting and forgot to remove that.